# Is there any software that will do face recognition in photos?

Tags: software-recommendation, search, photo-management

I would like to automate the process of tagging my photos with subjects' names.

Is there any software for Ubuntu that can perform face recognition on a local photo collection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Digikam**](http://www.digikam.org/)

(...will in the next release, very soon. there may be a beta/development version that does now. please read:)

*"Aditya Bhatt added face detection and recognition to digiKam. He says: 'Because of my project, digiKam can now automatically detect faces in photographs. It allows you to tag these faces with People Tags, and can also identify unknown faces and automatically tag them. My work also introduced a wrapper library called libkface that can be used by other KDE apps. Right now everything works okay, but it needs a bit of usability and GUI work, as well as some tweaks to libkface. **Hopefully my work will make it in time for the Christmas release, which will be 2.0!**'"*

this is taken from the latest google summer of code update on kde.org, here:
[**http://dot.kde.org/2010/12/14/kdegoogle-summer-code-2010-part-1-2**](http://dot.kde.org/2010/12/14/kdegoogle-summer-code-2010-part-1-2)
[image]

Comment: I just tried it on my exported facebook photos and it did not find a single face on them.  It seems like a research project was done 6 years ago and it is broken now.

Comment: Google photos (mentioned below) does, however, recognize people and correctly categorizes them by person.

Answer (score 5):

**Google photos, [the successor to Picasa](http://googlephotos.blogspot.com/2016/02/moving-on-from-picasa.html)**[image] may satisfy your demand. You just drag and drop the pictures folder to google photos (website - but it's actually native code via Chrome's Native Client) which automatically organizes them - you can go to Albums -> People to see all them categorized by recognized faces.

**[OpenCv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)**(Open Source Computer Vision) also has the Linux versions.It is a library of programming functions for real time computer vision.Many software about recognition of photos also use opencv.Opencv can also solve your problem definitely.

The face recognition result:

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how you were able to test out face recognition in Picasa 3.0 for Linux?

Comment: Google has his own technology to recognize the red eye and faces.Picasa can manage photos by collecting photos with faces or red eye together automatically.But it also take some time to classify the photos.

Comment: Are **you** able to tag photos using face recognition in Picasa for Linux?

Comment: Last time I checked, the Linux version of Picasa (3.0 IIRC) did **not** do face recognition. It was the only reason for me to reboot to Windows.

Comment: @oKtosiTe Ah,then I suggest you  learning something about **Opencv**,The result of face recognition has been added to my answer.

Comment: Picasa for linux is just a wine app with a couple of integration tricks. You can install it and them overwrite it files with the last windows release. Last time that I tested it worked nicely, and it did face tagging.

Comment: Picasa isn't avaiable for linux anymore

Comment: The link for picasa is broken, do you know of an alternate.

Comment: Google Photos does an awesome job recognizing faces, but unfortunately this information is not stored anywhere but on Google servers. As far as I know, there's no way to get this information and properly tag an image with it, like question asks.